# how to group radio buttons in custom listview

Tags: android, image, listview, radio-button, custom-lists

I am working with custom **listview with images and radio buttons**. Now I want to group these radio buttons. Here is my `xml` and the java class program.

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
 <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/image"
    android:layout_width="55dip"
    android:layout_height="55dip"
    android:scaleType="centerCrop"
    android:src="@drawable/stub" />

<TextView
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/text1"
    android:layout_width="208dp"
    android:layout_height="?android:attr/listPreferredItemHeight"
    android:layout_weight="0.56"
    android:checkMark="?android:attr/listChoiceIndicatorSingle"
    android:gravity="center_vertical"
    android:paddingLeft="6dip"
    android:paddingRight="6dip"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
    android:textColor="#000000" />

<RadioButton
    android:id="@+id/radioButton1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
```

```
     public class LazyAdapter extends BaseAdapter {

private Activity activity;
private String[] data;
private String[] conditions;
private static LayoutInflater inflater=null;
public ImageLoader imageLoader; 

public LazyAdapter(Activity a, String[] d, String[] c) {
    activity = a;
    data=d;
    conditions=c;
    inflater = (LayoutInflater)activity.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    imageLoader=new ImageLoader(activity.getApplicationContext());
}

public int getCount() {
    return data.length;
}



public Object getItem(int position) {
    return position;
}

public long getItemId(int position) {
    return position;
}

public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    View vi=convertView;
    if(convertView==null)
        vi = inflater.inflate(R.layout.item, null);

    TextView text=(TextView)vi.findViewById(R.id.text1);      
    ImageView image=(ImageView)vi.findViewById(R.id.image);
    text.setText(conditions[position]);
    imageLoader.DisplayImage(data[position], image);


    return vi;
}
```

and the second class of java..

```
     public class WeatherCondition extends Activity {

ListView list1;
LazyAdapter adapter;
ImageButton done,cancel;


@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.weather_conditions);
    done=(ImageButton)findViewById(R.id.imageButton1);
    done.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            Intent intent = new Intent(WeatherCondition.this, AddWeatherAlarm.class);
                startActivity(intent);

        }

    });

    cancel=(ImageButton)findViewById(R.id.imageButton2);
    cancel.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            Intent intent = new Intent(WeatherCondition.this, AddWeatherAlarm.class);
            startActivity(intent);
        }

    });       



    list1=(ListView)findViewById(R.id.list);        

    adapter=new LazyAdapter(this, mStrings,conditions);


    list1.setAdapter(adapter);
    list1.setChoiceMode(ListView.CHOICE_MODE_SINGLE);

    list1.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1,
                int arg2, long arg3) {
        Toast.makeText(WeatherCondition.this, ""+conditions[arg2],Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

        }

    });


}

String conditions[]={ "Clear/Sunny","Partly Cloudy","Cloudy","Overcast","Mist","Patchy rain nearby","Patchy snow nearby","Patchy sleet nearby","Patchy freezing drizzle nearby","Thundery outbreaks in nearby","Blowing snow","Blizzard","Fog","Freezing fog","Patchy light drizzle","Light drizzle","Freezing drizzle","Heavy freezing drizzle","Patchy light rain","Light rain","Moderate rain at times","Moderate rain","Heavy rain at times","Heavy rain","Light freezing rain","Moderate or Heavy freezing rain","Light sleet","Moderate or heavy sleet","Patchy light snow","Light snow","Patchy moderate snow","Moderate snow","Patchy heavy snow","Heavy snow","Ice pellets","Light rain shower","Moderate or heavy rain shower","Torrential rain shower","Light sleet showers","Moderate or heavy sleet showers","Light snow showers","Moderate or heavy snow showers","Light showers of ice pellets","Moderate or heavy showers of ice pellets","Patchy light rain in area with thunder","Moderate or heavy rain in area with thunder","Patchy light snow in area with thunder","Moderate or heavy snow in area with thunder"};

   }
```

}

Comment: What is your problem...?

Answer (score 0):

```
Add the radiogroup to your row layout like this I have added 

<LinearLayout
  xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  android:layout_width="match_parent"
  android:layout_height="match_parent">


  <RadioGroup
  android:layout_width="wrap_content"
  android:layout_height="wrap_content">

  <RadioButton
  android:layout_width="wrap_content"
  android:id="@+id/radio1"
  android:text="alpha"
  android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>

    <RadioButton
  android:layout_width="wrap_content"
  android:id="@+id/radio2"
  android:text="beta"
  android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>



  </RadioGroup>
</LinearLayout>
```

and your adapter should have something like this

```
public class adapter extends ArrayAdapter<String>
    {

        public adapter() {
            super(rtt.this,R.layout.test,arr);
            // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
        }

        @Override
        public int getCount() {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            return arr.length;
        }

        @Override
        public int getPosition(String item) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            return super.getPosition(item);
        }

        @Override
        public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            LayoutInflater li=getLayoutInflater();
            View row=li.inflate(R.layout.test,parent, false);

            RadioButton a=(RadioButton)row.findViewById(R.id.radio1);
            RadioButton b=(RadioButton)row.findViewById(R.id.radio2);

            return row;
        }



    }
```

this is just an example, please modify it to suit your needs 
CheckedTextView  you can go ahead and remove that it won't be neccesary.

Comment: so u want to say that if i have  48 buttons in the list so i will have to set 48 radio butoons ???

Comment: what is 48 buttons thing ???? that's what we use layout inflaters for this code works fine just add it to the row layout you must be creating a layout for single row there.

Comment: @Pragnani my code just work fine but  instead of single choice iit is it gives me multiple choice selection.

Comment: 48 means 48 radiobuttons. i dont knw how to do it thats y  i asking. i am using the button with listview

Comment: Apologies if my previous comment offended you, no you don't need 48 radiobuttons, just add as much as required like 4 radiobuttons for the four answers to select from. and you need to check for only them in your adapter and handle the oncheckedchangelistener inside adapter only.

Comment: lets discuss this in chatroom, I am upvoting this question so that you will get chat privlages

Comment: this is what i want to this . itis a listview including images and the radio buttons. now in the xml file when i try to add CheckedTextView as for customlistview. it won't check anyone of it bt if put seprate radio button with textview for custom list it checks multiple item at the same time ...

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/24959/discussion-between-saman-and-aashish)